# Error "The page you requested was not found."

Tags: rte

I cannot save entry due to this error!, its occurs when we copy paste TEXT from Word Document to Expression Engine Entry "Body" (using RTE field) we get above error, it stated when the server was upgraded to Php 8.0, 8.1, and EE 6.4.11

Comment: Try copy/pasting the data as plain text, then formatting it there-after. I suspect some of the data is causing an error in the POST request. Happy to help further if you need it.